# Spring Cloud Config JDBC Backend

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-jdbc, spring-cloud-config

I have the necessity to configure a Spring Cloud Config Server for read the properties of the variuos instance from a JDBC Backend (PostgreSQL) instead of Git repository. I follow the official documentation, but doesn't work. 
I add to application.properties of Spring Cloud Config Server

```
spring.profiles.active=jdbc
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
```

and I create the table inside database

```
CREATE TABLE public."PROPERTIES"
(
    "APPLICATION" character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "PROFILE" character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "LABEL" character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "KEY" character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "VALUE" character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
```

and, for the eureka server, I insert

```
INSERT INTO public."PROPERTIES"
("APPLICATION", "PROFILE", "LABEL", "KEY", "VALUE")
VALUES('discovery-service', '', '', 'spring.application.name', 'discovery-service');
INSERT INTO public."PROPERTIES"
("APPLICATION", "PROFILE", "LABEL", "KEY", "VALUE")
VALUES('discovery-service', '', '', 'server.port', '8761');
```

The Eureka Server, if I use this parameters inside Git repository, works fine, but using the JDBC backend, doesn't work. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Doesn't work isn't very descriptive. Can you provide more details? What does a call to http://<configserver>/discovery-service/default look like?

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Nov 28 15:59:27 CET 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT KEY, VALUE from PROPERTIES where APPLICATION=? and PROFILE=? and LABEL=?]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERRORE: la relazione "properties" non esiste Position: 24

Comment: Can't find the properties table? Sounds like a configuration problem

Comment: I'm assuming the quotes in the SQL make it case sensitive, why did you do that?

Comment: Hi Did you got any success ?? I too need it But I am getting blank values from database

Answer (score 2):

The PSQLException saying "properties" does not exist is because PostgreSQL is case-sensitive. When using PGAdmin to create table/column, the tool automatically adds the quotes if the name is in all caps, thus making it case-sensitive.

You can try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE public.properties
(
    application character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    profile character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    label character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    key character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    value character varying(500) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)

INSERT INTO properties
("application", "profile", "label", "key", "value")
VALUES('myconfig', 'default', 'master', 'my.message', 'hello');
```

The application.properties contains:

```
server.port=8888
spring.profiles.active=jdbc
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/configdb
spring.datasource.username=xxxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxx
```

You can now access using http://localhost:8888/myconfig/default